# How to fix error loading DiagnosticAnalyzerFieldsAnalyzer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, roslyn-code-analysis

Visual Studio 2022 was installed on clean Windows 11 using Web Development profile.

Running existing ASP.NET 6 MVC project in it using F5 throws error in build window

```
NuGet package restore failed. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project MyApp could not be loaded.
```

Error window contains number of warnings

```
>     Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>      Warning  CS8032  An instance of analyzer Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.CSharpDiagnosticAnalyzerFieldsAnalyzer
> cannot be created from
> C:\Users\kobru\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codeanalysis.analyzers\3.0.0\analyzers\dotnet\cs\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Analyzers.dll:  Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers.MetaAnalyzers.DiagnosticAnalyzerFieldsAnalyzer`4'
> from assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers,  Version=3.3.3.10305,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'..
```

Will this stop code analyzer? How to fix this so that warnings to not appear?

Comment: There is no  `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers` package in Dependencies/Packagages.  This package is listed only in Dependecies/Analyzers and there is no remove command in Analyzers

Comment: After adding this package in nuGet package manager error disappers. You can wrote this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the *NuGet package restore failed...* error means that the required package doesn't exist in the NuGet [*global-packages*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) folder or the package installation is corrupted.

The simplest way to resolve this problem is to install/reinstall the package by using the NuGet Package Manager or perform the following command from the Package Manager console in the Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package package_name
```

---

*An additional information:*

*[Install and manage packages in Visual Studio using the NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio)*

*[Manage packages with the Visual Studio Package Manager Console (PowerShell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-powershell)*